# Laravel whereJsonContains with multidimensional array

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, mysql-json

I do have a JSON type database field `attributes` in MySQL 8. This field contains a JSON string with this format:

```
    {
    "094e4f67-f427-4c3c-9f98-1d45585596de": {
        "price": 4.66,
        "title": "Prissy Pink",
    },
    "0b6ce397-af06-484a-bf6b-cfc92333f838": {
        "price": 4.66,
        "title": "Cameo Rose",
    },
    "0baf95f8-6ee5-47da-b827-69dc160c7127": {
        "price": 4.75,
        "title": "Petrol Blue",
    }
}
```

Now I want to query this JSON field with Laravel 8/Eloquent to find all products with attribute title "Petrol Blue".

When I try

```
Product::whereJsonContains('attributes->title','Petrol Blue')
```

I do not get any results - because of the multi array I think.

How to query correctly?

```
Product::whereJsonContains('attributes->*->title,'Petrol Blue')
```

also does not work.

I even tried

```
Product::whereJsonContains('attributes.*.title,'Petrol Blue')
```

with no results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think your json should like this:

```
[
    "094e4f67-f427-4c3c-9f98-1d45585596de": {
        "price": 4.66,
        "title": "Prissy Pink",
    },
    "0b6ce397-af06-484a-bf6b-cfc92333f838": {
        "price": 4.66,
        "title": "Cameo Rose",
    },
    "0baf95f8-6ee5-47da-b827-69dc160c7127": {
        "price": 4.75,
        "title": "Petrol Blue",
    }
]
```

Not like this

```
{
    "094e4f67-f427-4c3c-9f98-1d45585596de": {
        "price": 4.66,
        "title": "Prissy Pink",
    },
    "0b6ce397-af06-484a-bf6b-cfc92333f838": {
        "price": 4.66,
        "title": "Cameo Rose",
    },
    "0baf95f8-6ee5-47da-b827-69dc160c7127": {
        "price": 4.75,
        "title": "Petrol Blue",
    }
}
```

```
Product::whereJsonContains('attributes', [['title' => 'Petrol Blue']])->get();
```

Comment: That's not working. I tried it before and I do not get any results ;-(

Comment: Which is your json type ? My first or second one ?

Comment: It's the second one, but I cannot change it - I have to use it the way it is! ;-(